# React Native and using npm modules

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

So this is the case: we developed a web application. Now we are developing an app in React Native with Firebase, for iOS and Android... Is there a way to make use of the npm private module that we developed for the web application? Do we need to initialise firebase/app as well in typescript? Or is it really needed to develop a seperate module for android and a separate module for iOS?

So in this npm private module there are standardized ways for our company to get and set data in firestore.

Regards, Peter

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, every package from npm is mapped or linked to one in the respective operating system, that is Android and iOS in your case.

> Is there a way to make use of the npm private module that we developed
> for the web application?
> Or is it really needed to develop a seperate module for android and a
> separate module for iOS?

When there is no respective implementation for the operating system, that "translates" your npm package, it will not work.

> Do we need to initialise firebase/app as well in typescript?

Yes indeed, also in react native you need to initialise firebase app.

> So in this npm private module there are standardised ways for our
> company to get and set data in firestore.

I cannot say why you did this in a custom way, if you use the "normal" firestore methods then maybe there is still a way to reuse some code? But that is hard to say from the outside.

Comment: So because there is a lot of duplicated data in a document based database. We created modules and functions to update information. So with one function, maybe 3 documents will be updated. We would like to use these function in react native as well, but the current modules use the firebase npm web based module.

Comment: Well, if it is only JavaScript that you are using to make special requests why putting it into npm? You can use those functions as part of your code?